# Getting parse error while installing the application in android 4.0.4

Tags: android

```
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageInstaller(5015): Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /mnt/sdcard/Download/downloadfile.apk
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:425)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageUtil.getPackageInfo(PackageUtil.java:74)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity.onCreate(PackageInstallerActivity.java:277)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-12 09:41:33.425: W/PackageParser(5015):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could you please how to resolve this issue.

Comment: are you sure the apk is signed properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try in eclipse right-click project -> android tools -> fix project properties
Then clean and build.

Comment: Thanx for ur reply..i have already tried the above..the problem is i have to download the apk from server and it is downloading properly..while installing i am getting the above error with android 4.0.4 version.

Comment: Can you try unzipping the apk then and seeing if the manifest file is in there?

Comment: My downloaded apk size is zero.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the package file to see if the Manifest.xml file is in there and contains the info you put in it.  .apk files can be opened with most zip utilities.  See the following link on the format: [apk file format on Wikipedea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29)

Without seeing the manifest.xml file it is hard to say any more.

Comment: Thanx for ur reply...the problem is solved.  *.apk is not downloading properly. that's why i am getting the error.

Comment: Santosh can you share the code used to download *.apk from a location to sdcard

Answer (score 0):

I invested some time on this error and found that there ca be 2 possibilities.

1. Either your apk is not building properly (try to clean project/uninstall from device or emulator and try building again).
2. Your upload is corrupted if you have uploaded your apk on some server.

Comment: I m updating through same application for update also.. How to achieve that..??